# Will an e-ATX motherboard fit in a large ATX form factor case?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, desktop-computer, case, form-factor

Is it possible (without drilling any holes or anything) to fit an e-ATX motherboard into a large computer case whose form factors are only ATX and micro-ATX? The case itself should have enough space in it to put the motherboard in, but will it have the right standoff positions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on the case manufacturer, who may or may not have provided pre-drilled holes/positions for the different form factor.

Comment: Would this be true for this: http://www.thermaltakeusa.com/Product.aspx?C=1277&ID=2101#Tab1

Comment: No, as the E-ATX (Extended ATX) has a length of 13 inches while that case has a max length of 12 inches.